# Kiel traduki el la angla "item", kiam oni ne povas uzi la vorton "elemento"?

Tags: programming

Saluton!

Mi devas traduki retejajn tekstojn, kie aperas ambaŭ anglaj vortoj "**item**" kaj "**element**". La diferencon inter la du bone klarigas tiu ĉi paĝo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427117/difference-between-element-item-and-entry-when-it-comes-to-programming

Komputeko sugestas la vorton "**ero**", sed mi preferus uzi ion alian, se eblas.
Ĉu iu ajn havas sugesto(j)n?

Dankon

Answer (score 5):

Se vi opinias **eron** tro nespecifa, provu **listeron** aŭ **kolekteron**. La signifo de `item` estas ero de grupo, komparu la etimologie afinan `itenary/iterate`. Ofte samspeca elemento, do `grupero`.

Answer (score 3):

Laŭ konteskto:

- aĵo (concrete object)
- enigo (entry)
- elemento (primitive object)
- ero (part of something)
- kozo (thing, entity)

Kie estas la teksto ke vi deziras traduki? Estus multe pli facila doni taŭgan respondon se vi provizus ligon al ĝi.

Comment: enigo laŭ PIV estas 'ago enigi'. La plej bone estas uzi enigaĵo.

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus "liniero" (ero el linio).

Comment: Tiam vi dirus "lin**i**ero". :)

Comment: Dankon, mi pravigis gxin.